# Shared Elasticsearch Index

Tags: api, elasticsearch, microservices

I'm working on a new implementation where I have some queries regarding the pros and cons of having a shared Database in a microservice architecture.

Context:

Service A listens to an event from Kafka and based on the parameters updates a particular table. This table is owned entirely by Service A and not shared. Some of the data in this table needs to be accessed by other services based on the value of a particular field.

My Approach:

Once the Table is updated, if we know that this data might be required by some other service(by checking the value of the field) write it to an ES index. I want to keep the ES index shared across services.

The other services would read the ES index whenever required. These services would use the index only for **read** while Service A is the only service which writes to the index.

Also, I've added a fallback API in Service A which hits the table in case ES is down. Please check out the diagram, I've added a link to that below.

Issues:

One issue I can think of is that if ES is completely down then Service A won't be able to write to ES and hence that row update will fail. How do I handle this?

I also need help figuring out the fundamental scalability and deployment issues that can be counter productive to a microservice architecture by introducing a shared ES index. I think I have eliminated some of the resiliency issues by adding a fallback API for the other services in case ES is down.

Please criticise my design. [Design Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82gbD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I see three options:

**Option A:** Service A needs to implement something equivalent to the [two-phase commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) where an event consumed from Kafka by Service A would not be acknowledged until both the DB and ES have acknowledged their write.
It puts a big burden on your service, which in case one of the two sub-system goes down (DB and/or ES) would have to spend time retrying, and is not able to consume more events from Kafka. Events would start piling up in the topic. 2PC is hard to implement right in a distributed environment.

**Option B:** Service A consumes from Kafka topic A, does its things and produces another event in another Kafka topic B. Two other consumer groups responsible for updating sub-systems would then consume those events from topic B, one would keep updating the DB and another would keep updating ES. Service A can do its job rapidly and not have to worry or get bogged down with updates. Each updates can be retried independently by each consumer group without impacting upstream event consumption. Eventually, everything will be in synched.

**Option C:** It's a variation of option B, more lightweight. Service A consumes events from the Kafka topic, does its job and updates the DB as it does now. Another process (CDC, Logstash, etc) consumes updates from the DB and updates ES asynchronously and is also responsible for retrying is ES is down. Eventually, everything will be in synched as well.

There are other options, but these 3 are the most obvious ones to me.

Comment: I'm leaning towards option C. This is because, Service A is already writing to the DB and there is no change in that. In case ES is down, Service A is not responsible to write to ES so it can keep processing the messages. Therefore there won't be any downtime for Service A. My only other concern, is this bad design since this ES cluster will be shared by multiple services? Although there is only one dedicated service responsible for the write and other services are just reading from ES

Comment: Option C is the simplest and the one that requires the less changes to your current architecture. Since you have a fallback API to search the DB in case ES is down, this means that ES is not a critical component and it's ok if it's not always up-to-date in real time.

Comment: Right. But is this design an anti-pattern to microservice architecture because of the shared ES cluster?

Comment: anti-pattern, how so? ES is distributed itself by nature and is meant to be accessed concurrently

Comment: A DB is being shared among services. Although with the fallback API there is no single point of failure for read. And if we remove the write responsibility to ES from service A then it shouldn't be an issue that ES cluster is shared among services.

Comment: ES is distributed itself by nature and is meant to be accessed concurrently. Depending on which DB you're using and how it's installed, it's more likely going to be the problem because traditional DBs are not distributed by nature. if you're DB is down, even your fallback API won't be able to respond to clients.